# Get method signature, username and password from SoapMessage object

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a SoapMessage (javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage) object type, that contain a soap message.
I would retrieve the name of the called operation in that soap.

I tried getChildElements or getChildNodes, but I does not like this way, because I have to iterate and check when the node if equal of Node.ElementType.

There a way or method like getMethod() or getMethodSignature() that I can use in some way?

And there is a way to get username and password from authentication token in a simple way (getUsername, getPassword) from that type of Object?

Suggests?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know tag names refers to username/password/signature?

Comment: @Fess I have to assume them not known